# A value coming from Autocomplete is set to undefined, why?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, autocomplete, material-ui, ref

I'm using a form that I send the data to function (`submitHandler`), and in the `submitHandler` function I get the data by referencing it to the form fields.
After it I bring it to the console and see the data there:

```
import { useRef } from "react";

function NewForm() {
const citiesRef = useRef();
const typeRef = useRef();
...

function submitHandler(event) {
   event.preventDefault();

   const enteredCities = citiesRef.current.value;
   const enteredType = typeRef.current.value;

   const printing = {cities: enteredCities, type: enteredType);

   console.log(printing);
   }

return (
<form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
...
<input type="text" id="cities" ref={citiesRef} />
<input type="text" id="type" ref={typeRef} />
....
```

Until now everything is working well.

When I start using the MUI framework and its Autocomplete component, the data that I get from the Autocomplete (using the `console.log`), is set as `undefined`.

instead of using the normal input text field, I wrote this:

```
<Autocomplete disablePortal id="cities" options={citiesList}
 renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="" />} ref={citiesRef} />
...
const citiesList = [
  { cityId: "472", label: "Name1 ",},
  { cityId: "473", label: "Name2 ",},]
```

Now the output in the `console.log` shows 'undefined'.
Does anyone have an idea why?

Note:
(When I try to directly send to console.log by using the `onChange` props, from the Autocomplete component:
`onChange={(event, value) => console.log(value)}` Works, and presents the correct array:

> (2) [{…}, {…}]
>
> 0: cityId: "472" label: "Name1 " [[Prototype]]: Object
>
> 1: cityId: "473" label: "Name2 " [[Prototype]]: Object
>
> length: 2 [[Prototype]]: Array(0)
>
> ).

Comment: Which `material-ui` version are you using?

Comment: I think the latest version. 5.3.1.

Comment: Please add a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).